# Is dgCat a category or a 2-category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories, dg-categories, 2-categories

Let us consider dgCat, the "collection" of all small dg-categories. In [On differential graded categories](https://atlas.mat.ub.edu/grgta/articles/Keller.pdf) and [Lectures on dg categories](http://www.mi.ras.ru/~akuznet/dgcat/Toen%20Lectures%20on%20DG-categories.pdf) the authors state that they form a category, i.e.  dgCat has small dg categories as objects and the dg functors as morphisms. They then give a model structure on dgCat.

However, as pointed in [What do DG-categories form?](http://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~tamarkin/Papers1/dg.pdf), it is more likely that dgCat is a 2-category: it does not make too much sense to say whether two dg-functors $F$ and $G$ are equal.  Instead we can talk about morphisms between dg-functors.

How to integrate these two viewpoint? In particular, could we still have a model category structure on dgCat if we treat it as a 2-category?

Comment: It's an $(\infty, 2)$-category.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is the Dwyer-Kan model structure has a interpretation in that $(\infty,2)$-category structure?

Comment: Model structures present $(\infty, 1)$-categories, but there should be more structure here than that.

Comment: You're aware that 2-categories are also ordinary categories, right?

Comment: At least if you use "2-category" in the Australian sense...

Comment: @Fernando: well, this is a bit tricky. It's true that a strict 2-category has an underlying category given by forgetting 2-morphisms, but I prefer to use a convention where n-category always means the weak thing by default, so with that convention, if you just forget 2-morphisms composition might fail to be associative (and in any case this operation doesn't respect equivalences of 2-categories). The model-independent thing to do is to take the homotopy category, but using the word "are" for this construction seems like sweeping something under the rug.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the fact is that dgCat is what you call a *strict* 2-category, and hence has an underlying category.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The model structure on the category of dg-categories presents an $(\infty,1)$-category DGCat.  This structure is essentially provided by the existence of mapping spaces (or mapping $\infty$-groupoids) between dg-categories.

To see why DGCat admits the further structure of an $(\infty,2)$-category, it is sufficient to see why these mapping $\infty$-groupoids can be refined to mapping $(\infty,1)$-categories, which give back our mapping $\infty$-groupoids when we pass to the sub-$\infty$-groupoids of invertible morphisms.

Such structure is provided by functor dg-categories, which are the internal hom objects in DGCat (in the "derived" sense -- these are denoted $R\underline{Hom}$ by Toen).  These functor dg-categories give $(\infty,1)$-categories (by using for example the Dold-Kan correspondence), which provide the mapping $(\infty,1)$-categories in the $(\infty,2)$-category DGCat.

(Toen showed that these mapping $(\infty,1)$-categories can also be described as the $(\infty,1)$-categories of right quasi-representable bimodules.)

Edit: I just noticed that the preprint [Giovanni Faonte, *$A_\infty$-functors and homotopy theory of dg-categories*, [arXiv:1412.1255](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1255)] appears to contain a precise construction of the $(\infty,2)$-category of dg-categories.

Comment: Can we construct an "actual" $(\infty, 2)$-category, say a $\Theta_2$-space or a quasicategory-enriched category? After all, there are such things as [sesquicategories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sesquicategory) which have hom-categories but otherwise fail to completely satisfy the 2-category axioms.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Gepner-Haugseng show that the $\infty$-category of $V$-enriched $\infty$-categories has an enrichment over itself, for $V$ a presentably $E_2$-monoidal $\infty$-category.  In particular this gives the enrichment of DGCat over itself, and hence via Dold-Kan an enrichment over $\infty$-categories.  (I'm using implicitly the rectification result of Haugseng, which implies that DGCat is equivalent to the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-categories enriched over the $\infty$-category of chain complexes.)

Comment: @Adeel Could you explain a little bit what does it mean by The model structure on the category of dg-categories "presents" an $(\infty,1)$=category DGCAT?

Comment: Any model category (in fact, even just a category with weak equivalences) gives rise to an $(\infty,1)$-category.  For example, if one takes simplicially enriched categories as a model of $(\infty,1)$-categories, this is given by the Dwyer-Kan simplicial localization.

Answer (score 11):

Adeel answer is perfect, I will be more basic. 
There is many notions of "2-category" structure here around. 
1) the category of small dg-categories $\mathbf{dgCat}$ is symmetric monoidal closed category. Closed means that there is an internal $HOM$ in the sense that for any two small dg-categories $A$ and $B$ there is $HOM(A,B)\in \mathbf{dgCat} $ such that there is a natural isomorphism of sets $\mathbf{dgCat}(X,HOM(A,B))\cong \mathbf{dgCat}(X\otimes A,B)$. That means $\mathbf{dgCat}$ is enriched over it self.

There is a functor from $H^{0}:\mathbf{dgCat}\rightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$ which gives you an enrichment of the category $\mathbf{dgCat}$ over $\mathbf{Cat}$, hence you can see $\mathbf{dgCat}$ as a 2-category.

On an other hand, the internal $HOM(-,-)$ described before has the wrong homotopy type, you can not derive it since it does not take Dwyer-Kan equivalences (between fibrant-cofibrant objects) to  Dwyer-Kan equivalences (the $\mathbf{dgCat}$ is not symmetric monoidal model category in the sense of Hovey). Bertand Toen constructed, for the model category $\mathbf{dgCat}$, the right notion of the derived internal hom denoted by $RHOM(A,B)\in \mathbf{dgCat}$ (using bimodules, I will not write the details). Moreover this new derived $RHOM(A,B)$ induces the derived Mapping space $Map
_{\mathbf{dgCat}}(A,B)$ via the nerve functor of some well choosen subcategory of $RHOM(A,B)$). This new derived internal allows you to see the category $\mathbf{dgCat}$ as $(2,\infty)$-category and in the same time as symmetric monoidal $(1,\infty)$-category.

An important consequence is the following isomorphism in $Ho(\mathbf{sSet})$:
$$Map_{\mathbf{dgCat}}(A\otimes^{L}B,C)\cong  Map_{\mathbf{dgCat}}(A,RHOM(B,C))$$